# Modifying the A star search of boost graph library

Tags: boost, shortest-path

I found this A star search implementation of boost library. It says that this implementation finds the shortest distances from the start vertex to every other vertex. However, I only want the shortest distance from the start vertex to the end. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: If it is finding the distance from the start to every other vertex, then it is not A*... more than likely, the documentation is misleading, and the algorithm CAN find the distance from start to every other vertex, but if you supply it an finish-vertex it will using A* to find the best path between the start and the finish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the implementation, there is probably a loop with condition

```
while (openQueue != empty)
    ...pop bestCostVertex, etc.
```

If you tweak the condition

```
while (openQueue != empty && bestCostVertex != endVertex)
```

where bestCostVertex is the vertex to be popped out of the openQueue, the vertexes in the openQueue are processed only till you find the endVertex.